# Add all previous numbers in a for loop

Tags: php

I have this simple for loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    echo $i . "<br>";

}
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now what I want is to add all the previous numbers on each loop. So the output should be:

```
1
2 // 2+1
3 // 3+2+1
6 // 6+3+2+1
12 // 12+6+3+2+1
24 // 24+6+3+2+1
...etc
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Also, just use $sum = $sum + $i;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple to achieve your result just use:

```
$sum = 0; // you need to intillize variable sum here
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + $i; //you can add all the value in sum and echo it.
    echo $sum . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hey, the code that you gave me is not exactly producing the results that I want. Please see this php fiddle: http://codepad.org/At4UFFjy

Comment: @MarwanAnsari Please check the line "Now what I want is to add all the previous numbers on each loop"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $total = $total + $i;
        echo  $total."<br>";
    }
?>
```

You can achieve this by adding the $i's value with $total value